# Natural French phrase for 'you got a strange idea for fun'?

Tags: expressions, anglais, formulation-idiomatique

The vocabulary needed seems simple enough but I'm struggling with composing a whole sentence. Is there a natural French phrase to say this kind of things half jestingly?

---

(You wave at total strangers just to see how they would react?)

- You got a strange idea for fun!

Comment: Hmm, I say "a strange idea *of* fun"! You really say "for"?

Answer (score 3):

The following suggestion is slightly off for it doesn’t directly call into question the level of strangeness of someone’s idea of fun, but rather how low they’ve set their “fun-bar” (i.e., how little it takes to amuse them), but it can, at least, be used to poke some good-natured fun at the activity and those who consider it to be fun:

> [**Ça t’amuse vraiment ?  Hé bien/Alors, il t'en faut {vraiment} peu** {pour
>   t’amuser/pour être heureux/euse}
>   !](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/il-ten-faut-peu.140661/)

(follow the above link to a *WordRefernce.com* thread discussing "il t'en faut peu")

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the already mentioned "*Tu as de drôles de façons de t'amuser !*", if you're going for something sarcastic:

> Ah bon... C'est original, comme façon de s'amuser.

Answer (score 2):

Good answers already :

- [This one](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/31712/13100), lightly facetious
  ***<sub>Tu [en] as de drôles de façons de t’amuser !</sub>***
- ...and [that one](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/31714/13100), a little more sarcastic
  ***<sub>Ah bon... C'est original, comme façon de s'amuser.</sub>***

To add more examples on the sarcastic side, I suggest :

- ***Ça amuse les enfants !*** → common in the area of Quebec where I grew up, back in the nineties. It has remained to this day, but it’s somewhat less used now.
- ***On s’amuse comme on peut...*** → implies to a certain point that the silliness of the game is a consequence of a poor imagination.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly<sup>1</sup> what the English sentence means, that might be:

> *Tu [en] as de drôles de façons de t'amuser !*

Or the colloquial:

> *T'es un peu [chelou](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chelou), toi !*

<sup>1</sup><sub>I guess I did, Flying_whale had the very same sentence in mind too...</sub>

Comment: You posted the exact same answer like 15 seconds before me :p, the meaning is a bit different, but another way could be `Un rien ne t'amuse` . To enphasis on the fact that the personne get fun easily

Comment: @Flying_whale That should rather be *Un rien t'amuse* then.

Comment: @Flying_whale 16 seconds precisely ... *Les grands esprits se rencontrent* ;-)

Comment: The plural "de drôles de façons" sprang to mind first, but now that I think about it, I can't put my finger on how the singular version compares: "Tu as un drôle de façon de t'amuser."

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens I'd rather suggest: *Tu **en** as **une** drôle de façon de t'amuser !*